# How to do inference for a FP16 TensorFlow model with non-fixed input shape in C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, mxnet, tensorrt

The model was trained with Python. I have looked into different ways but hit the wall here or there. I summarize as below and please correct me if I am wrong

```
+--------------------+-----+-------+-----------------+
|                    | C++ | FP 16 | non-fixed shape |
+--------------------+-----+-------+-----------------+
| TensorFlow C++ API | ✓   | ?     | ✓               |
| TensorRT           | ✓   | ✓     | X               |
| TF-TRT             | X   | ✓     | ✓               |
+--------------------+-----+-------+-----------------+
```

- At least TensorRT 5.1 [still doesn't support non-fixed input shape](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048706/tensorrt/tensorrt-5-1-support-dynamic-input-size-/)
- TF-TRT = [tensorflow/tensorrt](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt) and for the moment it is only avaiable in Python
- I am aware of TensorRT Inference Server but I don't want to go into a network communication based solution if I don't have to

The "?" in the table means the interplay with `Eigen::half` under [tensorflow/core/kernels](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/kernels) (e.g., inside [conv_2d_gpu_half.cu.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_2d_gpu_half.cu.cc)) to achieve FP 16 arithmetic with TensorFlow C++. I don't see many documentation on this but is it the only way to go?

(I am fine with converting my model to other frameworks like MXNet but similar limitations seem apply: 
just change TensorFlow C++ API→[MXNet C++ Package](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/cpp-package),
TensorRT→[TVM](https://github.com/dmlc/tvm/issues/3042), and TF-TRT→[MXNet-TensorRT](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/tutorials/tensorrt/inference_with_trt.html) in the table)